# How are function attributes transparently viewed by a method

Tags: python, methods, attributes

I recently wrote a number of functions that needed a marker attribute:

```
def fn1(): pass
fn1.mark = True
```

The actual marking was done by a decorator, but that it neither here nor there. My worry was that when I marked methods in a class in the same way, the marker would not be visible when the method was bound:

```
class A:
    def meth1(): pass
    meth1.mark = True
```

But in fact the attribute was visible just fine:

```
>>> fn1.mark
True
>>> A.meth1.mark
True
>>> A().meth1.mark
True
```

However, the attribute can not be assigned to or deleted in the bound method, as it can be in the function:

```
>>> A().meth1.mark = False
AttributeError: 'method' object has no attribute 'mark'

>>> del A().meth1.mark
AttributeError: 'method' object has no attribute 'mark'
```

How are the attributes of a method made visible when it is bound?

Comment: Question to your question - does a function/method attribute  contribute anything towards the func/meth itself? I tried `def fn2(): print("foo" if mark else "bar")` but when assigned `fn2.mark = True; fn2()` I'm greeted with `NameError` (as expected).  Seems kinda counter intuitive for an object to have an attribute that's not accessible within itself? I'm understanding your attribute can only contribute to the outer scope.  e.g. `[f() for f in funcs if f.mark]`

Comment: @Idlehands: Attributes and local variables are completely separate things. Attributes are accessible within the function as long as you actually perform attribute access instead of variable lookup: `print("foo" if fn2.mark else "bar")`.

Comment: This is the same situation as with instance attributes and method local variables, where methods need to use `self.whatever` instead of just `whatever` to access attributes.

Comment: Thank you @user2357112, that cleared things up.  Just a confusion on my end! This is very neat and potentially allows more flexibility, thank you to you both.

Comment: @Idlehands. Another way to think about it is that the code of a function lives in a code object, which can potential be referenced by multiple function objects, so referencing the attributes of one of them doesn't make much sense. You don't see this much, but imagine a nested function, like what a decorator often returns. The code object gets compiled once when the function is first referenced. But every time you call the decorator, a new function object is created, possibly with different attributes every time. All those functions refer to the same code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Method objects implement `__getattribute__` to delegate attribute access for unknown attributes to the underlying function object. They don't delegate `__setattr__`, though, which is why the assignment failed. If you want to see the code, it's [`method_getattro`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.1/Objects/classobject.c#L135) in `Objects/classobject.c`.